# C# how to get time duration and sampling frequency of a rxbuffer

Tags: c#

Hello I am newbie  at C# and also at socket. I am working with a code where some values of an accelerometer  are coming to my to my pc using socket. The values are being stored as a buffer in the code. The code is taking number of samples and calculating sensor's value corresponding  to the particular sample. The values arw saved in rxData. And the number of samples is rxLength in the code. The socketReceived function has been passed in a thread. Thread thread= new Thread(threadStart(socketReveived());
Thread.Start();
How can I get the time duration of the signal coming to my pc as rxData and the sampling  frequency.  Furthermore, how to set a user defined sampling frequency  for the signal?. TIA for your help

```
private int[] rxData = new int[0xFFFFFF];

private int rxLength = 0;

public void socketReceived() 
{       
    byte[] rxBuffer = new byte[0xFFFFFF];
    
    int startLen = 0, dataLen = 0;

    while (isConnected) 
    {
        try
        {          
            startLen = getSeqeunce(START_CODE);
    
            Console.WriteLine("startLen:" + startLen);
    
            if (startLen != -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("rx start");
                this.Invoke(new Function(updateTextBox), "Measuring");
                readFully(rxBuffer, 4); 
                dataLen = (rxBuffer[0] << 24) + (rxBuffer[1] << 16) + (rxBuffer[2] << 8) + rxBuffer[3];
                //rxLength = dataLen / 2;
                rxLength  = Convert.ToInt32(tbIP1.Text);

                Console.WriteLine("rxLength:" + rxLength);
                readFully(rxBuffer, dataLen);

                this.Invoke(new Function(updateTextBox), "Converting");
                for (int i = 0; i < rxLength; i++)
                {                      
                    rxData[i] = (short)((rxBuffer[i * 2]) + rxBuffer[i * 2 + 1] * 256);
                        
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i, rxData[i]);

                    curveSensor.AddPoint(i, rxData[i]);
                }
    
                this.Invoke(new Function(updateTextBox), "Displaying"); 
    
                zgSensor.AxisChange();
    
                zgSensor.Invalidate();
    
                this.Invoke(new Function(updateTextBox), "Measurement completed"); 
    
                Console.WriteLine("rx end");
                    
                this.Invoke(new Action(delegate ()
                {
                    btnStart.Enabled = true;
                    btnSave.Enabled = true;
                    btnCustom.Enabled = true;
                }));
    
                isComplete = true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}

private void updateTextBox(string str)
{
    lbGraphMessage.Text = str;
}

private void sendPacket(byte[] data, int size) 
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
    
    int checksum = 0, index = 0;

    try
    {
        if (isConnected)
        {
            buffer[index++] = 0x42;
            buffer[index++] = 0x4D;
            buffer[index++] = (byte)((size + 2) >> 8); 
            buffer[index++] = (byte)((size + 2) & 0xFF);
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                checksum += data[i];
                buffer[index++] = data[i];
            }
            buffer[index++] = (byte)(checksum >> 8);
            buffer[index++] = (byte)(checksum & 0xFF);
            for (int i = 0; i<index; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0:X} ", buffer[i]);
            Console.Write("\n");
            ns.Write(buffer, 0, index);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void readFully(byte[] buffer, int size) 
{
    int offset = 0;
    int readBytes;
    do
    {
        readBytes = ns.Read(buffer, offset, size - offset);
        offset += readBytes;
    } while ((readBytes > 0) && (offset < size));
}

private int getSeqeunce(int[] sequence) 
{
    int seqIndex = 0; 
    int c;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) 
    {
        c = ns.ReadByte();

        //Console.WriteLine("readbyte:" + c);
        if (c == sequence[seqIndex])
        { 
            seqIndex++;
            if (seqIndex == sequence.Length) return i + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            seqIndex = 0;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you share what you tried to set a user defined sampling frequency for the signal

Comment: Hello, Sarlo thank you so much for the reply. I am a very beginner in this area. I haven't used anything yet to set a user defined sampling frequency. I am wanting suggestion that how can I set the user defined sampling frequency. Thank you again